# Need Help starting DSE Graph

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

When I type in the following command "dse gremlin-console" the system tries to start but then i get the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Asssitive Technology not found: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper

Do i need to update my Java version?

Answer (score 0):

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/datastax/labs/issues/10) with Docker images that should be eventually fixed.

The linked issue has 2 workarounds:

1. Install `openjdk-8-jdk` into Docker image after it's started
2. Disable assistive technologies for OpenJDK with something like this:

```
docker-compose exec --user root dse bash -l \
  -c "sed -i -e '/^assistive_technologies=/s/^/#/' /etc/java-*-openjdk/accessibility.properties"
```